# How do I set a variable to the output of two commands in Bash

Tags: bash

I read [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash) and tried to do that twice:

```
TESTVAR=$(echo 1) $(echo 2)`
TESTVAR="$(echo 1)" "$(echo 2)"
TESTVAR=`echo 1` `echo 2`
```

All three options fail with `-bash: 2: command not found`.

Bash version 4.3.30

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that bash runs the two commands, captures their outputs, and then substitutes that to produce `TESTVAR=1 2`. That assigns 1 to TESTVAR and tries to run 2. Apparently, there's no executable called "2" on my PATH.

The second attempt with quotes came close, but the quotes don't belong to the individual substiturions. You need a single pair:

```
TESTVAR="$(echo 1) $(echo 2)"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `TESTVAR=$(echo 1; echo 2)`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. That's another option.

Comment: I simplifies things a bit because there's only one command substitution, and it wouldn't have to be quoted.